# Scripting/Parsing Apple Motion 5 .motn files

Tags: python, animation, xml-parsing, finalcut

I'm new to animating and I've started using Apple Motion 5

http://www.apple.com/au/final-cut-pro/motion/

The interface can be a bit annoying by not letting me do things in bulk or automate things. Since it saves files in a nice xml format I've been kinda hacking it to do things I like.

e.g setting Fixed Resolution off for hundreds of assets wasn't possible in the app without doing each one manually so I wrote a short script to find and replace this line in the file setting value to 0

```
<parameter name="Fixed Resolution" id="113" flags="8606711808" default="1" value="0"/>
```

Are there any python libraries that parse/script .motn files? (other than generic xml parsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try `Awesome Python` at https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python
>
> Maybe you'll find there what you're looking for.
>
> But if you really want to use cool app try ***`The Foundry Nuke`*** or ***`Blackmagic Fusion`*** instead of Apple Motion or Adobe After Effects. Nuke and Fusion are node-based flexible and powerful compositing applications that support python scripting and programming. There are non-commercial free versions:

https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke/

https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion

Hope this helps.